# mac: py2app not finding cacert.pem

Tags: python-requests, py2app

My app created with py2app is not able to find cacert.pem.  The error stack shown below says it's looking into the zip file in the app bundle.  I checked the zip file and the cacert.pem seems to be in the right place.

I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4171) to copy cacert.pem to the requests package so it can be found during p2app compile, with no success.

I am using Anaconda with python 3.5 on Mac.

Any ideas?

```
  File "/Users/chuck/Documents/patelco/monitor/dist/monitor.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 98, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/chuck/Documents/patelco/monitor/dist/monitor.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 82, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/chuck/Documents/patelco/monitor/dist/monitor.app/Contents/Resources/monitor.py", line 82, in <module>
    send_text_message(report_text)
  File "/Users/chuck/Documents/patelco/monitor/dist/monitor.app/Contents/Resources/monitor.py", line 46, in send_text_message
    message = client.messages.create(to="+1510845xxxx", from_="+1415758xxxx", body=msg)
  File "twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/message/__init__.pyc", line 92, in create
  File "twilio/base/version.pyc", line 205, in create
  File "twilio/base/version.pyc", line 47, in request
  File "twilio/base/domain.pyc", line 46, in request
  File "twilio/rest/__init__.pyc", line 122, in request
  File "twilio/http/http_client.pyc", line 68, in request
  File "requests/sessions.pyc", line 618, in send
  File "requests/adapters.pyc", line 407, in send
  File "requests/adapters.pyc", line 226, in cert_verify
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/chuck/Documents/patelco/monitor/dist/monitor.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python35.zip/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Comment: ahh nice, what version of `requests` are you using?  I filed an issue in `requests` and put in a PR to fix it a few months ago: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4369

Comment: actually... the fix may have not made it to a release yet but if you can package the development version of requests available on git this should be fixed

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in `requests` that was [recently fixed](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4369) but has not made it to a release version yet. If you are ok with using a development version of requests, you can install from the github repo (upgrading if already present) so that when you build your app you have the latest version with this fix:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/requests/requests/zipball/master
```